# I have a problem with my MySql 'SELECT' command

Tags: c#, winforms, datatables, mdf

I want to get the first id from my table and write it at `label16.text` to create a pages for my program.Why the following code returns system.threading.tasks.unwrappromise'1[system.object]?

```
await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();               
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id from Recipes order by id asc limit 1", sqlConnection);
label16.Text = command.ExecuteScalarAsync().Result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```cs
label16.Text = command.ExecuteScalarAsync().Result.ToString();
```

To

```cs
var t = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
label16.Text = t.Unwrap().ToString();
```

And to fullfill the answer, I'll paste this from comments too.

Another thing you have to do, is fixing your SQL query, it should be

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) Id from Recipes order by id asc
```

Third question

I'd do that this way

```cs
try 
{
    var id = int.Parse(label16.Text);
    sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM Recipes WHERE Id = {id}", sqlConnection);
} catch { // error handling }
```

Comment: Is .Unwrap() necessary? cause i get this: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Incorrect syntax near 'limit'."

Comment: So, if it's MSSQL as I get, you should do

`SELECT TOP(1) Id from Recipes order by id asc`

Comment: wait, if you still here how to get the value of label.text and make id that value? i tried that and it works, but i need to change 8 to label16.text. `sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Recipes WHERE Id = 8", sqlConnection);`

Comment: I've edited the answer so there's answer on this too